# Restrict generic type T to not being undefined in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I defined the `get(o, key)` function that should work with any Object that satisfy the `{ get: (key: K) => R }` interface.

Additionally I would want to restrict the result `R` to not being `undefined`. Is that possible?

How to to change the example below so that it won't compile, because of method `Params::get(key: string): number | undefined` that returns `undefined`?

```
function get<K, R>(o: { get: (key: K) => R }, key: K): R {
  return o.get(key);
}

class Params {
  constructor(public values: { [key: string]: number }) { }

  get(key: string): number | undefined {
    return this.values[key]
  }
}
const params = new Params({ a: 10 });

console.log(get(params, "a"))
```

Comment: According to this thread, it seems like the "best" approach is to use an exhaustive list of types base, unfortunately: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7648 - however that's what the Utility Types are for: I assume you'd want to use `NonNullable<T>` (though this also excludes `null` in addition to `undefined`).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do it with `NonNullable<T>`, but not as a constraint on the type-parameters, but using it as an interface-type on `get`'s `R`, like so:

```
function get<K, R>( o: { get: (key: K) => NonNullable<R> }, key: K ): NonNullable<R> {
  return o.get(key);
}
```

So this code gives me an error:

```
const params = new Params({ a: 10 });

console.log(get(params, "a"))
```

> Argument of type '`Params`' is not assignable to parameter of type '`{ get: (key: "a") => number; }`'.
> The types returned by 'get(...)' are incompatible between these types.
> Type '`number | undefined`' is not assignable to type '`number`'.
> Type '`undefined`' is not assignable to type '`number`'.(2345)

The catch is that `NonNullable<T>` prohibits both `undefined` and `null` - which may or may not be desirable in your application.

#### Update

I found the definition of `NonNullable<T>` in `lib.es6.d.ts`:

```
/**
 * Exclude null and undefined from T
 */
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
```

This can be tweaked to restrict only `undefined`:

```
type NonUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T;
```

and if I change `get` to this:

```
type NonUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T;

function get<K, R>(o: { get: (key: K) => NonUndefined<R> }, key: K): NonUndefined<R> {
  return o.get(key);
}
```

Then this works exactly as you've requested: it allows `class Params`'s `get` to return `number | null` but not `number | undefined`.

Answer (score 14):

There are no subtraction/negated types in TypeScript, but you can express "not `undefined`" as "`{} | null`" instead.  Any non-`null` and non-`undefined` value is assignable to the empty type `{}`, and if you want to accept `null` and not `undefined` you can use `{} | null`:

```
function get<K, R extends {} | null>(o: { get: (key: K) => R }, key: K): R {
    return o.get(key);
}
```

This works the way you expect:

```
console.log(get(params, "a")); // error!
// -----------> ~~~~~~
// Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type '{} | null'
```

while a similar type that returns just `number` instead of `number | undefined` will not be an error:

```
const numberGetter = { get(key: string) { return 123 } };
console.log(get(numberGetter, "b")); // okay
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKFDMFcDsGMBcCWB7aACA5gU3gHgNIA0aASmlgB7xbQAmAzmgN4C+aAPmtJADY8B8ACmQAuZphxjBAaywBPMfgCUaALz9SaFsVkK0ysWSag0ptACcckc+mQA6bPBnylAblAtQoWDwCG9RgAFX3NfAFtGYxAzNFhUenhzSARkc0EAB0gAIx5EWDQAN18eSCx6MSY0AG1dMQTzRGgMAF0xbjCsrHMtFUrPMGizR2c9esaMJTbIDq6ONBhaLHBGrFpmExizS3hrdHgAC0R6OyKSspr5Zo3Tfv646AS0dJDwxlUuLAB3NGDQiMFKr4xABGAAMPXcA3u9GQPCwdh4yAwgmGzz+9GIACJfJilG40AB6AnkczmVIAQlARLQAFo6fSGTSNAA-VlsqnEgAqcnSWDQAHJ2p1upwFksVrR+WgjlxkPA0P56IgMNBfDk+fBkGh4Dy+fzWHNuHx+V4QND5UKugBxHDUbrvSrDWpoMZNXoWKw2NDAgBMAGYtFpIdDYfDEcjhpbzDb4HasVlcfjqchpL45GggA)

Comment: Doesn't `type foo = {} | null` preclude scalars like `number` and `Symbol` though?

Comment: No, `{}` includes primitives like `string` and `number` and `symbol`.  Only `null` and `undefined` are excluded, because they give you a runtime error if you try to access properties on them.  Other primitives will be auto-wrapped at runtime and seem to have properties and methods like `toUpperCase()`, so they are considered "object-like" by TS.  Only the `object` type in TS actually excludes primitives.

Comment: `There are no subtraction/negated types in TypeScript`; actually, this is exactly what [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) [does](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgGwQQwEYIgZWAJwJYB2A5lALxQDOuhRAPgYggNwCwAUOwMYD2BVUDJGgzZ8xALIBJGAFVMsgDIKoALgCiAD04I4AEwgAeeEPRZqxADQDGAPjLWkTIA). If you mean "you cant do an anti-undefined", well, yeah, you can do that too using generics: `type AntiUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T;`

Comment: @Hashbrown [The `Exclude` utility type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) can only filter a union; it is not doing true subtraction of types, as evident by the fact that `Exclude<unknown, undefined>` or `AntiUndefined<unknown>` both evaluate to `unknown`, and `undefined extends unknown`. This might not be a big deal for `undefined`, which doesn't overlap with most non-union types in TS (only `unknown` and `any`?). But you'll be sad if you try wider non-union types, like `Exclude<string, "">` or `Exclude<{a: string | number}, {a: string}>`.

Comment: OP doesn't care for those specifics, but if you want to do those you'd need to do something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdsAlgHgCoBooFVMDUB8UAvFKlBAB7ARwAmAztlAPynlU0NS4tRwQA3CACcoALjYT+Q4QG4AsACglAYwD2cesChbB0EgG8AhmIDsAXyhHG6zcAWLbWq-XojtY+EmShIagGY61EKYxmJwAK4AtgBGIgA+WsKIcADm5qEmkbEi5oQkukKyQA)

Comment: Sure, but now you don't have a specific type (`ThisMinusThat`), you have a type constraint (`ThisMinusThat<T>` where `T` is the type of some candidate value you're checking).  Until and unless something like [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) is merged into a release, there are no genuine subtraction or negated types in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Since NonNullable will exclude both `null` and `undefined`.

This will simply exclude only `undefined`.

```
type NonUndefined<T> = NonNullable<T> | null;
```

And this will simply exclude only `null`.

```
type NonNull<T> = NonNullable<T> | undefined;
```

Comment: your NunUndefined definition would add null to the type even if null is not in T. Idem with NonNull and undefined.