# How to use Typescript generics when the argument could be a value or callback function

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, typescript-generics

So here the problem is that I want to pass `T` which could be `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `object` or `array` or a `function` the thing is I can't figure out how to process `ab("hello")` in this case and have T returned back as a value.

```
function a<T>(ab: T | ((v: T) => T)) {
    if (typeof ab === "function") {
        return ab("hello");
    } else return ab;
}
```

this is the error I have been seeing and [link to error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwDwBUB8AKZAjALkXUQB9FtsA3I9ASkQF5Ni6GBvAKER8RmApQAngAcApnAH4mjRogBEoSLATyO3XpoBOYqCC1J82eQAsxAG3Nw1Abg08AvogsBnMYh16DKPHYdA)
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: I don't get it. Do you get any errors? The code seems fine

Comment: It doesn't ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwDwBUB8AKZAjALkXUQB9FtsA3I9ASkQF5Ni6GBvAKER8RmApQAngAcApnAH4mjRogBEoSLATyO3XpoBOYqCC1J82eQAsxAG3Nw1Abg08AvogsBnMYh16DKPHYecgA))

Comment: I assume this is a minimum reproducible example, but you call ab with `string`, but ab takes in the parameter type `T`. Can you try to recreate the example in a better way?

Comment: @Konrad  pasted the error and the playgound link

Comment: @LeoDog896, sorry this is the best way to recreate the example without showing the actual source code, the problem I am facing is the same, think of it as a setter value like `useState` which can take a value or a returning function

Comment: TS bug, Issue description and workarounds here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37663

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to restrict your `T` to not be a function

```
function a<T>(ab: T extends Function ? never : T | ((v: T) => T)) {
    if (typeof ab === "function") {
        return ab("hello");
    } else return ab;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwDwBUB8AKZAjALkXUQFMAPKUsAEwGdEAxcaeJAfkTFIDdSAnRERIAfRNmw9hASkQBeTMWmyA3gChEmxDGDioATwAOpOLvzy5cxACJQkWAmuqNW1-1JQQ-JPmzWAFqQANkFwTgDcLpoAvmRBdKSI7p7eKHiR0WpAA)

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63045455/5089567

Maybe there is another solution, but I don't know it